# Can't compile project on ARM with HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: uwp, arm, html-agility-pack, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to develop a Universal App for Windows 10 using HTMLAgilityPack.

When I'm trying to compile on ARM, I got an error stating that the HtmlAgilityPack.dll in ther uap10.0 folder is only for x86 processor.

Is that normal ?

Is there a chance HTMLAgilityPack to become available for ARM processor ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was an error on the compilation of 1.5.3 and 1.5.4. Everything is OK on 1.5.5.